# Why im getting 2 different results on the same seed number?

Tags: python, random, rounding, random-seed

I tried two different ways to get a coin flip result, seeding the RNG first in order to get reproducible results.

First, I tried using `random.randint`:

```
import random

random.seed(23412)

flip = random.randint(0,1)
if flip == 0:
    print("Tails")
else:
    print("Heads")
```

For this seed, I get a Heads result; the `flip` result is `1`.

Then, I tried `round`ing the result of `random.random`:

```
import random

random.seed(23412)

flip = random.random()
print(flip) # for testing purposes
new_flip = round(flip)

if new_flip == 0:
    print("Tails")
else:
    print("Heads")
```

This time, I get a value for `flip` of `0.27484468113952387`, which rounds to `0`, i.e. a Tails result.

**Why does the result differ?** Shouldn't `random.randint` pull the same random value (since the seed was the same), and flip the coin the same way?

Comment: Because you generated two random numbers.

Comment: thankyou so much, that looks like what i meant in my head. i am still learning a lot as i go... asking questions the correct way is one of them

Comment: Fortunately, I also know the answer for this question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeding a random number generator ensures a reproducible stream of *underlying raw data*. Different `random` module methods will compute their results in different ways, using different amounts of data.

The exact computation is an implementation detail. In the implementation I use (although I suspect it is the same for many other versions), `random.randint` will use the next *single bit* of raw data from the stream - it does a bunch of math first to figure out how many possible answers there are in range, then rounds that up to the next power of two, then chooses the corresponding number of bits to get a value (0..2<sup>n-1</sup>), repeats that until it's in range, and finally does more math to scale that to the original range. (If you tried, for example, `random.randint(0, 2)`, it would repeatedly grab two bits interpreted as an integer, until the result isn't `3` which is out of range.)

The implementation of `random.random` is hidden in the C code, but I assume that it grabs multiple bits of data (at least 53) in order to fill the mantissa of a machine double-precision floating-point value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, its very technical and i don't understand it fully but i am sure the more i study the clearer it will become. I did grasp the basic concept though and I appreciate you time. :)

Comment: It will probably help to study first the underlying theory of how random number generators work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set a seed, all random numbers that follow will be *consistent*. It does not mean that all random numbers will be the *same* (and not be random any more).

However, once you re-set the seed, the random number generation will start from the beginning. Therefore it's predictable what will happen, e.g. like this, where 200 random numbers are generated in a 100 loops and I can predict each outcome (via assertions)

```py
import random

for i in range(100):
    test_seed = 23412
    random.seed(test_seed)

    flip = round(random.random())
    assert flip == 0                # predict "Tails"
    if flip == 0:
        print("Tails")
    else:
        print("Heads")

    flip = random.randint(0,1)
    assert flip == 1                # predict "Heads"
    if flip == 0:
        print("Tails")
    else:
        print("Heads")
```

Comment: sorry i didn't explain my problem well enough to start with. hopefully the edit clarifies my issue, i thought it had something to do with round() but i could be(most definitely) wrong

Comment: Wait, hold on. Are you saying that you have **two completely separate programs**, where one of them uses `round(random.random())` with that seed value, and the other uses `random.randint(0, 1)` with that seed value?

Comment: yeah thats it, im very new here and dont know how to portray that in my answer so i just did them 1 above the other. but when i run the program i only use 1 method at a time. and with the seed number being 23412
ive also confirmed that the random number is the same yet the top program returns tails and the bottom program returns heads

Comment: I will edit the question to ask it properly. There are numerous other things that can be improved in the style of asking.

Comment: thanks for your help on making this clearer, ive done yet another edit and hoped that would help but if you have a better way im all ears!

Comment: Not sure if it's fair to modify the question in a way that existing answers  no longer answer the question. The way you had your code initially does absolutely not match the question as it is now.